# What's the best way to Invoke a service on spring-boot start up?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I have a spring boot application and i need to invoke a service(a rest end point)on start up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [CommandLineRunner](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner)

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements CommandLineRunner {

    public void run(String... args) {
        // Do something...
    }

}
```

You can perform any task you'd like at Application startup with this handy interface.

To call a REST endpoint you can use **[RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-resttemplate)**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://www.example.com/api/resource", String.class);
```

If you build a POJO with fields that match the JSON response, the RestTemplate will automatically map them with the help of Jackson.  See the docs for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to take a look at `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

i'd use and implementation of [ApplicationRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could also hook your app on the `ApplicationReadyEvent` or other events triggered by the Spring :

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners